# Perform operation on some (not all) dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary called `spectradict` which is composed of 5 different keys (multiple values per key), and I'd like to multiply each value under 4 of the keys by some constant A. I've figured out how to multiply all the values (under all the keys) by the constant:

```
spectradict.update((x, y*A) for x, y in spectradict.items())
```

But I only want the values under `spectradict['0.001']`, `spectradict['0.004']`, `spectradict['0.01']`, `spectradict['0.02']` to be multiplied by A. I want the `spectradict['E']` values to remain unchanged. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform conditional checks on your generator function by appending `if <test>` to the end of it.

```
spectradict.update((k, v*A) for k, v in spectradict.items() if k != 'E')
# or, inclusive test using a set
spectradict.update((k, v*A) for k, v in spectradict.items() if k in {'0.001', '0.004', '0.01', '0.02'})
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. However it's taking a while to run since my dictionary is very large (each key has thousands of values) -- do you know of a quicker way to accomplish the same task?

Comment: As in `v` is very large, or as in there are many keys? If it is the former, then the method you handle updating your dictionary will probably have little impact. I'd suggest creating a new question specifically about the efficiency of whatever operation you're doing. If it's because there are many keys, a toy benchmark I just did suggests it would be more efficient to create a updated dictionary from scratch using a `{generator expression}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the keys explicitly:

```
#UNTESTED
spectradict.update((x, spectradict[x]*A) for x in ['0.001', '0.004', '0.01', '0.02'])
```

Or, you could just exclude `E`:

```
#UNTESTED
spectradict.update((x, y*A) for x, y in spectradict.items() if x != 'E')
```