# Operations on dictionary values have no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to loop through the values of my dictionary and apply simple operations on it. These two SO articles unfortunately did not help me ([Perform an operation on each dictionary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010536/python-perform-an-operation-on-each-dictionary-value), [Perform operation on some not all dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120684/perform-operation-on-some-not-all-dictionary-values))

My dictionary contains the following data:

```
dict = {'WF:ACAA-CR (auto)': ['Manager', 'Access Responsible', 'Automatic'],
        'WF:ACAA-CR-AccResp (auto)': ['Manager', 'Access Responsible', 'Automatic'], 
        'WF:ACAA-CR-IT-AccResp[AUTO]': ['Group', 'Access Responsible', 'Automatic']}
```

My final objective is to set a label on the key based on the value it contains. For example, 'a' would be 'Workflow 2' because it has the value "Manager".
But first I just want to ensure that I can run an operation based on the dictionary values.

My code is:

```
for key, values in dict.items():
    if values == "Manager":
        print(key)
```

My previous attempts included:

```
if key.values() == 'Manager':
    print(key)
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/UserAR2-extract.py", line 28, in 
>       if key.values() == "Manager":
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

For the code:

```
for key in dict.values():
    if key == "Manager":
        print(key)
```

I do not get any output.

**How can I apply operations on dictionary *values*?**

Comment: first of all, it's bad form to overwrite the name `dict`

Comment: What is `dict_2`?

Comment: When I the lines under "my code is", I get the output "a". Are you not getting this result?

Comment: What output are you getting? If I run your code, I get "a" printed to the terminal...

Comment: Sorry, I corrected now my dictionary. I thought I will add an easier dictionary as example but it turned out obviously that it was working. However, with this dictionary, I do not get any output, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that you want to `print` if `Manager` is in the `list` of values. You just need to change your check from equality (which only occurs if the value is `"Manager"` alone, not in a `list`) to containment:

```
for key, values in dict.items():
    if "Manager" in values:
        print(key)
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I think this achieves what you are looking for.

```
myDict = {'a': "Manager", 'b': "Automatic", 'c': "Group"}

for myKey, myValue in myDict.items():
    if myValue == "Manager":
        print(myKey, myValue)
        myDict.update({myKey: 'Workflow 2'})

print(myDict)
```

Comment: Thank you for your example!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a copy of the dict and iterate over that as changing values or keys while iterating over them is bad practice. Also it's bad to use dict as a name for an object as it's a built-in method in python

```
from copy import copy

data = {'a': "Manager", 'b': "Automatic", 'c': "Group"}
data_copy = copy(data)

#Now we can iterate over the copy and change the data in our original
for key, value in data_copy.items():
    if value == "Manager":
        data["Workflow 2"] = data.pop[key]
    #and so on
```

After this is ran you should end up with:

```
data = {
    'Workflow 2': "Manager",
    'b': "Automatic",
    'c': "Group"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is that what you're looking to do in the end?

Comment: The key should remain 'a' in your example now, but a new value or the values should be replaced by the label. So that I am able to relate the key to the label.